# What String'!' means in Swift when used as a parameter?

Tags: swift

Well, `var s: String?` means a nullable string, and when I know `s` isn't `null`, I use `s!`

But what's the meaning of, for example, `init(parameter: String!)`?

Comment: Well presumably it means the same thing - `parameter` can't be null. (Presumably enforced on callers.)

Comment: Using this (logical) thinking, init(par: String) is the same of init(par: String?)

Comment: Well can you declare other `var s: String!` is a variable? (I don't know any Swift...)

Answer (score 1):

It means that the optional parameter will be implicitely unwrapped.

thus you can do something like

```
class Person {
var name : String
init(_ n : String!) {
    name = n
}
}
var name : String? = ...
var px = Person(name)
```

Comment: Please, be aware that this is not the same as unwrapping it explicitly. If you write name! when it's None, it will crash, but if you pass parameter of type Type! it may work even when you pass None. Example:
func test(param: String!) { println(param) };
var s: String?;
test(s)

Comment: Thanks for this explanation... so using this same example, Person only accepts 'String?' ? Can I pass a String?

Comment: In example with Person, you can pass both: String? and String.

Comment: Ok, my first comment wasn't clear. To variable of type Type! you can assign both values: Type and Optional. So you can pass None to parameter of type Type!, but this will likely lead to crash - operator "!" suggests that you don't need to check for value existence (in that case, you probably want to have parameter of type Type?).

Answer (score 0):

Please look for “Implicitly Unwrapped Optional Type” in book “The Swift Programming Language.” by Apple Inc. 
There is explanation, what exactly does it mean Type!, and also that it has default value of nil.